# Trouble Getting Access Token from StockX API (OAuth2)

Tags: c#, access-token

I am attempting to retrieve an access token from the StockX API using OAuth2 authentication. I have followed the documentation provided by StockX here and have implemented the following C# code:

csharp

```
private async void simpleButton16_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clientId = "6yZdVNq48X_the rest of my token";
    var clientSecret = "JVqpAdmJP0a3Uh_aUwPb_ the rest of my token";

    // StockX token endpoint
    string tokenEndpoint = "https://gateway.stockx.com/api/v1/oauth/token";

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Create a request body with client credentials
            var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret)
            });

            // Send a POST request to the token endpoint
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, requestContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Parse and extract the access token from the response
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // You may want to use a JSON parser to extract the access token from the response content.
                Console.WriteLine("Access Token: " + responseContent);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to obtain access token. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However, I keep receiving this response:

> "Failed to obtain access token. Status code: Forbidden".

I have double-checked my client ID and client secret, but I'm still facing this issue.

Can someone help me identify what I might be doing wrong in this code or point me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

Documentation is here : https://developer.stockx.com/portal/authentication